# Why is this BeautifulSoup result []?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.3

I want to get the text in the span. I have checked it, but I don't see the problem

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import socket

searchurl = "http://suchen.mobile.de/auto/search.html?scopeId=C&isSearchRequest=true&sortOption.sortBy=price.consumerGrossEuro"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(searchurl)
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.findAll('span',attrs={'class': 'b'}))
```

The result was `[]`, why?

Comment: You got an empty list `[]` because `findAll` didn't find anything.

Comment: There's no `span` tag with a attribute class value `b`.

Comment: i have a span with class=b . i think the problem is the return is a table of string i have to iterate

Comment: Show exact HTML that you want to extract from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the site in question, your search result turns up an empty list because there are **no spans with a class value of b**. BeautifulSoup does not propagate down the CSS like a browser would. In addition, your urllib request looks incorrect. Looking at the site, I *think* you want to grab all the spans with a `class` of `label`, though it's hard when the site isn't in my native language. Here's is how you would go about it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2    # Note urllib2

searchurl = "http://suchen.mobile.de/auto/search.html?scopeId=C&isSearchRequest=true&sortOption.sortBy=price.consumerGrossEuro"
f = urllib2.urlopen(searchurl)  # Note no need for request
html = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for s in soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class":"label"}):
    print s.text
```

This gives for the url listed:

```
Farbe:
Kraftstoffverbr. komb.:
Kraftstoffverbr. innerorts:
Kraftstoffverbr. außerorts:
CO²-Emissionen komb.:
Zugr.-lgd. Treibstoffart:
```